# Get value from resource bundles using substitution in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2, internationalization, struts-tags

How can I get localized text in resource bundles using a substituted key?

I tried following code, but not work:

```jsp
<s:i18n name="global">
  <s:text name="${top[0]}"></s:text>
</s:i18n>
```

I use `<s:iterator value="#request.myArray">` where `myArray` is an `ArrayList` of pairs of strings and each element of the array represents the key from resource bundle.

ex: `[{"a","1"},{"b","2"},{"c","3"}]`

```jsp
    <s:iterator value="#request.myArray">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:i18n name="global">
                <s:text name="${top[0]}"></s:text>
            </s:i18n>
            <s:property />
        </td>
      </tr>

</s:iterator>
```

and `${top[0]}` is `a,b,c` etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "using substitution" ? `<s:text name="foo.bar" />` is enough to retrieve the value from the `foo.bar` key on the most approriate bundle, according to the locale selected, if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use EL inside Struts' tags attributes. But you can use OGNL.

```jsp
<s:text name="%{top[0]}"></s:text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<s:text name="global">
   <s:param>${top[0]}</s:param>
</s:text>
```

where i.e:

```
global = some text with param {0}
```